# Flutter can't run with vscode but can run with xcode

Tags: flutter

I use xcode to build fullter_gallery, the app can launch and run.
But when use vscode to build flutter_gallery, I got this:

```
Invalid record-to location: bugreport ("process" is not empty)
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:26:3)
#1      getRecordingSink (package:flutter_tools/src/base/file_system.dart:114:9)
#2      getRecordingProcessManager (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process_manager.dart:29:25)
#3      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:271:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:109:29)
#5      new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#6      CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:109:11)
#7      FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:211:18)
#8      run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:59:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#12     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#13     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#14     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:42:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:50:10)
#17     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:52:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#18     main (file:///Users/yiqiwang/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#19     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:287:32)
#20     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
Exited (1)
```

I have run `flutter doctor -v`, and No issues found!

Comment: How do you run Flutter on Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

I delete bugreport folder and restart vscode, then everything is right.